# Linq Query for Employee Details using Where Conditions?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have a table like as below.

```
Eno Ename             Salary

1   Ravindra Tagore    60000

2   Mahesh Babu        80000

3   rama               20000

4   Krishna Prasad     25000

5   sita               40000

6   Subhash Varma      20000
```

I need a LINQ query for who are having more than 20k and also Last name not null Details.

Example

```
1 ravindra tagore 60000

2 mahesh babu     80000

4 krishna Prasad  25000.
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb688085

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Can you post what code for you've tried so for, or explain what you're having difficulty with?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your entity collection is called `Employees' the following query should work:

```
var results = 
from employee in dc.Employees
where employee.Ename.Trim().Contains(" ")
select employee;
```

The query will trim the spaces of the `Ename` column and if no space is found within the name it means that a part of the name is missing.

Comment: Ok Mr.RePierre Thanks for your feed back